# struct dirent in C d_name[256] and NAME_MAX definition

Tags: c, directory, readdir, dirent.h

I am confused by the use of `d_name[256]` and `NAME_MAX` in struct dirent definition. Does `d_name[256]` mean that the filename length can be atmost 256 character? Then it also mentions NAME_MAX (quoted in the bottom). So, my question is how `NAME_MAX` relates here and where can I find `NAME_MAX` value and definition?

In `man readdir` `struct dirent` is defined as following.

```
struct dirent {
    ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
    off_t          d_off;       /* not an offset; see NOTES */
    unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
    unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                    by all filesystem types */
    char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
};
```

It also asserts that

> The only fields in the dirent structure that are mandated by POSIX.1
>          are: `d_name[]`, of unspecified size, with at most `NAME_MAX` characters
>          preceding  the  terminating  null byte ('\0'); and (as an XSI exten‐
>          sion) `d_ino`.  The other fields are unstandardized, and  not  present
>          on all systems; see NOTES below for some further details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NAME_MAX` is declared in `limits.h`. You can also use `pathconf()` or `fpathconf()` to get the per-filesystem limit.

```
long max = pathconf(pathname, _PC_NAME_MAX);
```

Since the structure has this hard-coded to `256`, it can't actually handle filesystems with longer filenames. So `NAME_MAX` will necessarily be at most `255` (which is indeed its value on my OS X machine).

Comment: NAME_MAX doesn't include the terminator, just strlen, so it matches d_name.